# ¿Cómo leer notificaciones de Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

Estoy intentando leer las notificaciones, mi código es:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver myNotification = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    }
};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance.
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.checkPerm(Manifest.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE);

    IntentFilter filterNotifications= new IntentFilter(NO SE QUE FILTRO PONER AQUI);
    registerReceiver(this.myNotification, filterNotifications);
}
```

El problema es que no encuentro que intent filter ocupar.

Cuando lo hago para llamadas ocupo `TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` y funciona sin problemas.

Ojala pudieran orientarme

Comment: A que te refieres con leer las notificaciones? No entendi esa parte.

Comment: Aleer las notificaciones que lanza por ejemplo whats app y facebbok en el sistema. Como las de esta imagen https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/images/notification_detail.jpg

Comment: No sera mosstrar una notificacion lo que quieres?

Comment: En realidad quiero leer la notificacion que crea otra aplicacion. Lo que busco hacer es saber quien me escribe mensajes de whatsapp

Comment: Alejandro, es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y además obtienes tu primera medalla. Además es **muy importante revisar [ask]** que te brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas.

Comment: Debes ser más especifico, que tipo de notificaciones, Push Notifications?  Quien y como las envía?

Comment: Jorgesys, gracias por la ayuda ya lei la información que me sugeriste. Extacto son push notifications. Veras mi problema principal es que deseo hacer un auto reply para whatsapp y facebook messenger. Justo ahora estoy con whatsapp. ya que esta plataforma no tiene api he leido que recomiendan leer las push notification que este programa genera cuando se recibe un mensaje. De ahi en teoria podria obtener el numero que envio mensaje. esta parte es la que no logro hacer funcionar

Comment: Lo lograste amigo, si es así podrías ayudarme?
Lo que pasa es que necesito hacer exactamente lo mismo, por cuestiones de trabajo...

Answer (score -1):

Se puede hacer lo que vos estas buscando, pero se hace desde un servicio "NotificationListenerService" Te dejo un post, esta en ingles, pero es fácil de seguir la implementan del código.

[NotificationListenerService](https://gmariotti.blogspot.com/2013/11/notificationlistenerservice-and-kitkat.html)

[Documentacion Oficial](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html)

[Aplicación de prueba](https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example/)

En el manifiest tenes que declarar el servicio

```
 <service
  android:name="it.gmariotti.android.examples.
        notificationlistener.SimpleKitkatNotificationListener"
  android:label="@string/service_name"
  android:debuggable="true"
  android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" >
  <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.service.
             notification.NotificationListenerService" />
  </intent-filter>
```

El usuario tiene que dar el permiso, en la siguiente ruta: "Settings" -> "Security" -> "Notification access".

Implementación del servicio

```
public class SimpleKitkatNotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    Notification mNotification=sbn.getNotification();
    if (mNotification!=null){
        Bundle extras = mNotification.extras;

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.INTENT_ACTION_NOTIFICATION);
        intent.putExtras(mNotification.extras);
        sendBroadcast(intent);

    }
}

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

} }
```

Y en el activity quedaría así

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected MyReceiver mReceiver = new MyReceiver();
public static String INTENT_ACTION_NOTIFICATION = "it.gmariotti.notification";

protected TextView title;
protected TextView text;
protected TextView subtext;
protected ImageView largeIcon;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Retrieve ui elements
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nt_title);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nt_text);
    subtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nt_subtext);
    largeIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nt_largeicon);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_autorize:
            Intent intent = new Intent
            ("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mReceiver == null) mReceiver = new MyReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(INTENT_ACTION_NOTIFICATION));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent != null) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            String notificationTitle = 
                      extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);
            Bitmap notificationLargeIcon =
                      ((Bitmap) extras.getParcelable(Notification.EXTRA_LARGE_ICON));
            CharSequence notificationText = 
                      extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT);
            CharSequence notificationSubText = 
                      extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_SUB_TEXT);

            title.setText(notificationTitle);
            text.setText(notificationText);
            subtext.setText(notificationSubText);

            if (notificationLargeIcon != null) {
                largeIcon.setImageBitmap(notificationLargeIcon);
            }
        }

    }
}}
```

Espero te sirva la respuestas

Comment: Ahí te agregue una app de prueba donde podes sacar el código que necesitas.