# Cómo leer notificaciones de otras aplicaciones

Tags: android

Lo que intento es poder leer las  notificaciones creadas por otras apps ( WhatsApp , facebook, Gmail , teléfono , sms) .

El problema que encuentro es que en la web de Android developers no encuentro la api necesaria.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes mira esta pregunta tal vez te sirva 
 https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105626/c%C3%B3mo-leer-notificaciones-de-android

Comment: Bienvenido revisa [ask] para realizar preguntas en el sitio. En cuanto a tu pregunta por seguridad esto no es posible.